Is projection of a closed subspace Borel?
Specifically, letting $E$ be a separable infinite-dimensional real Banach space, and $D_2$ in $E\times E$ a closed linear subspace, is then $\{\,x:\exists\,y\,;(x,y)\in D_2\}$ a Borel set in $E\,$? Does the situation change if $D_2$ is known to be a ("graph" of a) function? Is there a reference or simple proof?
Remark added after the answer of @DavidGao : For the result a subspace of a Lusin space is Lusin iff it is Borel used in that answer wikipedia gives as reference Corollary 2 of Theorem 5 on page 102 in L. Schwartz' book Radon Measures on Arbitrary Topological Spaces and Cylindrical Measures. I wasn't aware of this result that directly implies ($*$) that for a continuous embedding $F\hookrightarrow E$ of separable Banach spaces the image of $F$ is Borel in $E\,$. This is what I ultimately need but was not optimistic enough to hope to get, and then was hoping that at least the result could be obtained in cases like $L^2\hookrightarrow W^{-1,2}\,$.
The above ($*$) even holds if we take $E=L^{+\infty}(Q)_{\text w}$ where the subscript means that the space is equipped with the weak$^*$ topology against $L^1\,$, by considering closed balls and noting that they are Polish spaces under that topology, provided that $Q$ is a suitably regular Euclidean domain.
I need ($*$) in order to consider Borel probability measures in $E$ that are centered on dense images of embedded spaces, that in turn is needed in the very interesting statistical approaches to existence of solutions to Navier−Stokes systems like in this and that paper of E. Feireisl and his research circle.

It is a Borel set. Indeed, let $P: E \times E \to E$ be projection onto the first coordinate. We need to show $P(D_2) \subset E$ is Borel. $P$, restricted to $D_2$, induces a bounded linear map $Q: D_2/\ker(P|_{D_2}) \to P(D_2)$, which is also a linear isomorphism (but not necessarily a homeomorphism). And we note that $D_2/\ker(P|_{D_2})$ is a separable Banach space, whence a Polish space. Thus, $P(D_2)$ admits a stronger topology that makes it a Polish space, namely the final topology induced by $Q$. That is to say, $P(D_2)$ is a Lusin space. $E$ is a separable Banach space, whence a Polish space, whence a Lusin space as well. A subspace of a Lusin space is Lusin iff it is Borel. Thus, $P(D_2) \subset E$ is Borel.

Thank you. See the Remark I added in original post.
